# Chrome call function in content scripts from background.js

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I've read the documentation but I still haven't been able to get this working.

Here is my manifest:

```
{
    "name":"app",
    "version":"0.1",
    "manifest_version":2,
    "description":"app",
    "background":{
        "scripts":[
            "scripts/modernizr.min.js", 
            "scripts/background.js"
            ],
        "persistent": false
    },
    "content_scripts": [
      {
        "matches": ["https://*/*", "http://*/*"],
        "js": ["scripts/content.js"],
        "run_at": "document_end"
      }
    ],
    "permissions":[
        "contextMenus", 
        "tabs",
        "http://*/*",
        "https://*/*"
        ],
    "icons":{
        "16":"images/icon_16.png",
        "128":"images/icon_128.png"
    }
}
```

I have a function in content.js called "myFunc". In background.js, I have a function, "myHandler" that is called by a contextMenus.onClicked listener. I want to call myFunc, from myHandler. I tried using tabs.executeScript, and tabs.query, but I can't seem to get the function to be called. Can anyone explain to me how I am supposed to let background.js call a function in content.js?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To call a function in the content script from the background page, you first need to know the tab id. `contextMenus.onClicked` event has a `tab` parameter containing that id. Then use [message passing](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging.html#simple) to do it.

For example, in your background page:

```
chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener(function(info, tab) {
  if (tab)
    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, {args: ...}, function(response) {
      // ...
    });
});
```

In your content script:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    sendResponse(myFunc(request.args));
});
```

Comment: Want to add that this API was changing during last 2 years, and that's how it looks right now.

Comment: @vittore Ah, that might explain why what I was trying wasn't working.