# How to access a page element from a background js of chrome extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I have a context menu in my chrome extension and now I need to capture a specific page elements when the user click on that menu.
This is my manifest file:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Capture",
  "description": "This extension is capturing all text elements in the page",
  "version": "0.1",
  "permissions": ["contextMenus"],
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["jquery-2.0.2.js", "background.js"]
  },
  "manifest_version": 2
}
```

background.js

```
function captureTextBoxes(e) {
    var textboxes = $(':text') ; 
        //alert(textboxes.length);
        textboxes.each(function (i){
        //code here
    }
}

chrome.contextMenus.create({
    title: "Capture All text box Elements", 
    contexts:["page"], 
    onclick: captureTextBoxes,
});
```

This was capturing 0 text box elements always. So I checked the passed document by adding following line:

```
    alert(document.documentElement.innerHTML);
```

It returns this :

```
    <head></head>
    <body style="">
        <script src="jquery-2.0.2.js"></script>
        <script src="background.js"></script>
    </body>
```

This is not my actual page, but a dynamic page created by the chrome itself. 
Is there anyway to access the actual page content that were right clicked for the context menu? (From a background javaScript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `contextMenus.onClicked` event (which triggers the callback specified by `onclick` ([in persistent background pages only](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contextMenus.html#property-createProperties-onclick))) is only available to the background page and the background page has no direct access to any web-page's DOM.

If you want to manipulate the web-page DOM, you have to:

1. Inject a content script into the web-page.
2. Pass a message to that content script, so it can manipulate the DOM for you.

<sub>(There are plenty of resources here in SO explaining how to achieve both.)</sub>

Take, also, a look at **[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18039277/chrome-call-function-in-content-scripts-from-background-js#answer-18039369)** to a similar question

Comment: Thanks a lot!. I did it with your help.